# |x|+|y|=\sqrt(2) using tikz or pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw the rhombus `$|x|+|y|=\sqrt{2}$` using `tikz` or `pgfplot`, but I am unable to do that.

I want to draw it, but despite several attempts, I am nowhere.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to draw it? Just for the shape (this ca be achieved with a simple rotated square) or to use it in a function problem?

Comment: Remember to alway show your attempts when asking a question. It tells us valuable information about what it is going to be used for and the expected result. -also this site is about conceptual problems -not about doing others work.

Comment: Sure. By the way, why was I unable to write my question in proper LaTeX?

Comment: My understanding is that https://tex.stackexchange.com is special regarding LaTeX code. Here people often needs to show code, so the site does not render it. -also people here know what the code means, so no need to render it.

Comment: Regarding why LaTeX output isn't shown, see [How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564) (read the comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal]
  \addplot [domain=-sqrt(2):sqrt(2), samples=3]{abs(x)-sqrt(2)};
  \addplot [domain=-sqrt(2):sqrt(2), samples=3]{-abs(x)+sqrt(2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rhombus graph]

Comment: It cannot be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I fill this rhombus green?

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala:   \fill[green] ({-sqrt(2)},0) -- (0,{sqrt(2)}) -- ({sqrt(2)},0) -- (0,{-sqrt(2)}) -- cycle;